# In .NET, does a parent class' constructor call its child class' constructor first thing?

Tags: java, .net

```
public class Parent
{
    Child child1;

    public Parent()
    {
        child1.Name = "abc";
    }
    ...
}
```

Gets a NullReferenceException. I thought the Parent() constructor calls the Child() constructor first, so that it is possible to access child1 object later in the Parent() constructor???

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an instance of the child; either initialize it as you define it:

```
Child child1 = new Child();
```

Or in the Parent constructor:

```
public Parent(){
    child1 = new Child();
    child1.Name = "Andrew";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The parent class's constructor doesn't call constructors for its members. When the member is a reference, it's just set to null. You need to explicitly allocate it by calling `child1 = new Child`

Answer (score 1):

Members are not implicitly constructed. They're initialized with their default values (i.e. `null` for reference type members), which is why your `child1` member is null.

You need to create an instance of `child1`:

```
public Parent
{
  child1 = new Child();
}
```

On a sidenote, I think you are being confused by constructor call rules for inherited classes. If your `Child` class inherited your `Parent` class, the `Parent` class' default (i.e. parameterless) constructor would be implicitly called (if it existed):

```
class Parent
{
  protected string member;
  public Parent()
  {
    member = "foo";
  }
}

class Child : Parent
{
  public Child()
  {
    // member is foo here; Parent() is implicitly called
  }
}
```